# On what condition on $\phi_n$ we can find $\alpha>0$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;\;\; \cos(\phi_n)\ge\alpha $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let $\{\phi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers, such that :  $\phi_n\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$  for all $n.$

**My question is** : On what condition on $\phi_n$ we can find (or we can prove unconditionally that there is ) $\alpha>0$ such that :
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;\;\; \cos(\phi_n)\ge\alpha $$

Thanks

Comment: @JohnBentin, Thanks for your comment, the condition $\phi_n\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is enough ?

Comment: No, its not enough as for example $\cos(\pi/2-1/n)\to\cos(\pi/2)=0$ from continuity of $\cos$.

Comment: The condition you need is that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ so that $\phi_n<\pi/2-\epsilon$ and $\phi_n>-\pi/2+\epsilon$ for all $n$. You could for example guarantee this by requiring $\phi_n$ converges *in* $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @s.harp, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It's useful to draw the functions to see intuitively the possible solution.

In the picture below, red line is $g(x)=\alpha$, blue graph is $f(x)=\cos{x}$. Anything in between the intersections of these two functions will satisfy $\cos{x}\geq \alpha$.

It also becomes evident that $1 \geq \alpha$, otherwise there are no sequences satisfying the condition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example, we could take $-\frac12\pi+\epsilon\leqslant\phi_n\leqslant \,\frac12\pi-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and all $n\in \Bbb N$.